# Attach horizontal line (ruler) to cursor

Tags: gnome, mouse, tracker, multi-pointer

I am currently reading a lot of texts on my computer, some which have wide rows, and shifting focus to write summaries. 
When I read on paper i sometimes use a ruler to keep track of my location, I find this helps when I get tired. Therefore, I would like something similar on linux.

Is there any way to code some transparent ruler that follows the mouse pointer? 
Most of the ruler applications like "kruler" are not attached to the mouse.

I also tried the cross-hairs in the accessibility but it's not quite what I want as i find the vertical lines distracting. And want something where I can set the opacity.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to start with this problem?

Best, 
Michael

Comment: ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, did that.

Have been searching quite a bit though so I'm not very optimistic about there being a ready-made solution. One can hope I guess : )

Comment: You want a ready-made solution, or you want to code one yourself? The former probably doesn't exist. If the latter, why not start with the existing solution you've tried, and modify them?

Comment: If a ready-made solution exists that would be great, but I haven't found one. 

I would imagine that I want to have some shape (rectangle) that follows the mouse pointer. 
Do you have some suggestion on which tools I can use to achieve this?

Comment: You can move kruler with the keyboard. Why do you need the mouse pointer while reading?

Comment: Yeah, i tried that but it's too slow. 
Also, it doesn't really jive with the hand position to have easy access to hotkeys for things like highlighting. 

More intuitive for me to use the mouse pointer as well.
Of course I don't *need* it. I do want it though : )